# Table design - limiting input to once a month

Tags: database-design

I am writing and iOS/iPad - SQLite app for a utility meter readings for in-house use. I would like to limit inputs to only one input per space per month. The current table design is field 0 - "ID" type: autoinc - integer, field 1 - "DATE" type : TEXT, field 2 - "ELECTRIC" type TEXT ... water, gas notes etc... with a compound primary key of DATE and SPACE. This works, limiting inputs to that space on THAT date but what if you are interrupted in the process of reading the meters and have to do it tomorrow, that is a new date and new key, you could have 2 sets of input for the same space in the same month, not what I want. Is there a way to limit inputs to 1 input per month per space?

hope this makes sense...

Answer (score -1):

Make a function based unique undex on the month-year part of the date and space.

Comment: I am always willing to learn something new so could you please elaborate? As for me, I went and got some food and quit thinking about it for a while, then in the middle of dinner it hit me... I am such and idiot... query the table for space data between the beginning of the month and the end of the month and if there is a result well, you have data for that space for that month... Thank you for replying.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support function based indexes. Or functions.